# How can I scroll to the top of a page using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to scroll to top of the page in php with javascript

```js
scroll(0,0); \\ this is not working?
```

On click of submit, i call a function to validate the form and incase of error i will be setting the errormessage thru innerhtml and need to scroll to top of the page without submitting.

Everything works...but its not scrolling to top of the page

Comment: That should work, maybe you're calling it incorrectly?
It could be that you're not triggering the action.

Comment: need to work javascript:scroll(0,0)

Comment: it needs to be triggered somehow, how are you calling scroll?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scroll to top of page with JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210798/how-to-scroll-to-top-of-page-with-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use window property scrollTop ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534618(VS.85).aspx), [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.scrollTop)) to set number of pixels to scroll offset.

```
window.scrollTop = '0';
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a particular element that you want to scroll over, lets say, the element of whose `innerHTML` you are modifying then you can use the following

```
 element.scrollIntoView(true);
```

Works in all browsers

Answer (score 1):

How about trying window.scrollTo(0,0). It is basically the same thing as scroll(0,0).

If it does not work, show us more code.

Answer (score 1):

Scrolling to the absolute top of the page can be achieved by either

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);
```

or

```
window.location = "#";
```

Note that the second method will append "#" to the current URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#">Scroll to Selected Position</a>
```

Above code worked for me. I tried with `onclick="window.scrollTo(0, 0);"` but this does not worked for me, all I needed was `href="#"` and no onclick. We might also notice that `#` will be getting appended in `url`.

Old non-working code has `href="javascript:scroll(0,0)"` which had an issue in doing scroll to top in angular/iframe component.

Above code does not worked in Firefox.

Final Solution:

```
function scrollToSelectedPosition() {
   var sectionToJump = document.getElementById('section-to-jump');
   $(sectionToJump).scrollIntoView();
}
```

and

```
<a onclick="scrollToSelectedPosition()">Scroll to Selected Position</a>
```

This worked in FireFox, Chrome, Safari and IE.