# Determining when images load in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

1. Is there a way to determine when
   a specific image asset has been
   loaded, either in a  tag or as
   a  background?
2. Is there a
   way to determine when ALL images in
   a page have been loaded?

If not, are there any jquery//alternative image loading techniques that would enable this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Use the `onload` event handler.

2) Use the `onload` event to increment a variable `imagesloaded` by 1, when `imagesloaded == document.getElementsByTagName('img').length` then all images have loaded

You may want to also use the `onerror` event, which fires when an image fails to load (for any reason), along with `onabort` for when the user aborts the connection.

Comment: This'll only work for <img> tags, it won't work for CSS backgrounds - I don't think it's possible to determine those. But you can have a dummy image with `display: none` - if the same source is used in several places then all instances of it load at the same time.

Comment: Interesting- So what types of elements fire onload- just img and windows?  What should I attach my handler to- the window, and then assume each onload event came from imgs?

Comment: Anything that requires fetching media from the server will fire an onload - this includes images, the new HTML5 audio and video tags (oncanplay and oncanplaythrough are recommended, but not supported by Google Chrome), and I think it also applies to script and link tags, though I'm not 100% sure on that.

Answer (score 1):

Handle the `onload` event of the (1) image or (2) window.

Comment: `document` has no load event, `window` does though ;)