# Scroll up button not working

Tags: scroll, blogger

I'm trying to put a scroll up (back to top) button in my blogger blog.

That should be, in principle, quite simple, but I don't why I can't manage to do it. Now after trying so many things I'm totally frustrated.

I'm using the following html code:

```
<a style="display:scroll;position:fixed;bottom:5px;right:5px;" href="#"><img src="url address of image" /></a>
```

The button is there as expected, but when I click on it, it reloads the blog instead of going to the top. Why?? no clue.

I tried to use an "id" in the logo image and link to it, and I've also tried to use in the blog head a name tag "name=Top" and link it with href="#Top".But it doesn't matter. It always reload the blog instead of going to the top.

For instance, when I'm inside a post and I click on the button it goes to the main page instead of scrolling up within the post.

If you want to check it yourself, please do it. My blog is [cortarcoserycrear.blogspot.com](http://cortarcoserycrear.blogspot.com)

Whatever help you can provide me it would be very appreciated because I don't know what's happening.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using Javascript/JQuery to do this.

Refer to this question: [How to scroll to top of page with JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210798/how-to-scroll-to-top-of-page-with-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

What I finally used to solve my problem was:

Button html:

```
<a style="display:scroll;position:fixed;bottom:5px;right:5px;" href="#wrap" class='go-to-top' title="Back to top"><img src="image url" /></a>
```

Body html:

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js'/>
  <script>
  $(function () {
  $(&#39;.go-to-top&#39;).click(function () {
  $(&#39;html,body&#39;).animate({
  scrollTop: 0
   }, 500);
  return false;
   });
   });
  </script>
```