# Single page app reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am writing a single page app with several divs that have the attribute `data-roll="page"`. Pushing buttons fires ajax queries and the user is redirected to divs down the document like this

```
 <body> 

<div data-role="page" id="menu">
//bunch of nav buttons like <a href="#faculty">
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="faculty" data-theme="b">
//dynamicly loaded list of faculty
</div>
```

and so on.

I want to return to the menu div on refresh but no amount of [scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210798/how-to-scroll-to-top-of-page-with-javascript-jquery)
seems to work. Here is my JS with two attempts at getting back to the menu `page` on page load.

```
document.ready = init;
function init(){

    var button = $('#facultyButton')
        ,facList = $('#facultyList')
        ,search = $('#facSearch')
        ,monikerBox = $('.monikerBox')
        ,events = $('#events')
        ,ajaxString = "http://stage.webscope.com/veith/dev/ajax.pl?"
        ,html = "";

    //executed on init
    $('html').scrollTop(0);

//events

    $(window).on('load',function(){
        $('html').scrollTop(0);
    });
    button.click(function(){
        var value = "a";
        search.html( "" );
        facultyAjax(value);
    });
```

I also tried `window.location=` menu url (home) in various functions with disastrous results!

Comment: Nice solution! Put it like the answer, because it's interesting this problem!

Answer (score 1):

Set the window.location you want the user to view with the location object on the load event.

I put this in the html.

```
<body onload="location.href='#menu'">
```