# How do I scroll to the top of the page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

How do I scroll to the top of the page with JavaScript after the page is completely loaded.

Comment: [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210798/how-to-scroll-to-top-of-page-with-javascript-jquery).

Comment: You can use `window.scrollTo(x, y)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210798/how-to-scroll-to-top-of-page-with-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `window.scrollTo(x, y)` where `x` and `y` are horizontal and vertical offsets in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var stepTime = 20;
var docBody = document.body;
var focElem = document.documentElement;

var scrollAnimationStep = function (initPos, stepAmount) {
var newPos = initPos - stepAmount > 0 ? initPos - stepAmount : 0;

docBody.scrollTop = focElem.scrollTop = newPos;

newPos && setTimeout(function () {
    scrollAnimationStep(newPos, stepAmount);
}, stepTime);
}

var scrollTopAnimated = function (speed) {
var topOffset = docBody.scrollTop || focElem.scrollTop;
var stepAmount = topOffset;

speed && (stepAmount = (topOffset * stepTime)/speed);

scrollAnimationStep(topOffset, stepAmount);
};
```

And then:

```
<button onclick="scrollTopAnimated(1000)">Scroll Top</button>
```