# Scroll to top not working for safari

Tags: javascript, safari, scrolltop

I am calling this javascript on page load

> document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;

I want html page starts from top when loaded, above javascript working fine for chrome, safari(macbook) but not working for safari on iphone,
can anybody suggest workaround in javascript only.

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/4210804/1693915 ?

Comment: I will give it a try, but why it is not working with above pure javascript?

Comment: Hi @LaljiGajera I just tested this on Xcode's simulator in oldest model (iPhone 5) and it did work. But things like `window.safari` flag checking didn't.

Answer (score 4):

Posting this here for future visitors from Google.
This same error occured to me... The problem was just one CSS rule on body element.

`overflow-x: hidden`

If this CSS rule exists, remove it and scrollTop should work on mobile Safari.

Comment: Why x? anyways, it works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I tested this before, there are problems rendering on ios, but it also depends on the version of the OS for example, for an iPad pro, there is no problem! But on iPad air you there isn't much to do! so what you can do is to make your code compatible like:

```
document.scrollingElement.scrollTop
```

it should give you the right solution.