# jump to a section without any change in url

Tags: javascript, html

To jump to a specific section in html page I can use `<a href="last-section"></a>`

or `window.location.hash='last-section'`, which change
the page's url like

`www.exmple.com/index.html#last-section`.

but is there a way to jump to that section without changing the url??

Comment: Yes, you can scroll the page to a section, _its id_ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210798/how-to-scroll-to-top-of-page-with-javascript-jquery

Comment: Yes, you can scroll with javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the element and use [`Element.scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView):

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("last-section");
elem.scrollIntoView();
```