# How to scroll to the top of the window in jquery when on click event

Tags: jquery

I want to know when on click event called the window scroll to top of the document with smooth scrolling behavior. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scroll to top of page with JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210798/how-to-scroll-to-top-of-page-with-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $("#header").offset().top
}, 500);
```

where `#header` is the top header

Comment: Thank you for your help. It helps me. If any other, I will back to you

Answer (score 1):

I hope you will get your answer here.

https://www.w3resource.com/jquery-exercises/part1/jquery-practical-exercise-2.php

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page-using-javascript-jquery/

**OR**

You can do with this syntex

```
$("body").scrollTop(0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I want scroll behavior as smooth