# How to scroll to top of the page when using Formik and Formik-Stepper for a multistep form

Tags: reactjs, formik

I would like the page to scroll to top when click Next to next Step

Comment: have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/4210821/5426560 ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` at event onClick of button:

```
onClick={() => {setStep((s) => s - 1); window.scrollTo(0, 0);}}
```